# React litle exercice for beginner doesnt work

Tags: reactjs

It's the first time I use React. I try to follow a tuto. I made exactly as the tuto but there is a mistake somewhere. I installed React, reactDOM, Bootstrap CDN in HTML file. I made the link between HTML and JS file.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      defer
    />
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
      defer
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      defer
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js" defer type='text/babel'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function BoilingVerdict({ celsius }) {
  if (celsius >= 100) {
    return <div className="alert alert-success">l'eau bout.</div>;
  }
  return <div className="alert alert-info">l'eau ne bout pas.</div>;
}

reactDOM.render(
  <BoilingVerdict celsius={50} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

[image]

What's wrong ?

Comment: JSX needs to be transpiled to `React.createElement` calls in order to work on the web

Comment: Do I have to add babel CDN ?

Comment: Usually, the React is transpiled server-side, and the transpiled JS is used in the webpage. take a look at [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/)

Comment: As explained in the tuto, this should ne work with CDN. Somone could copie/past my code in ordre to test it ?